# Как разместить блоки в линию,а не друг под другом

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня по какой-то причине не получается вставить блоки в одну линию,они находятся друг под другом
[Ссылка на codepin](https://codepen.io/zesshhi/pen/BarmQKK)
Вставить js code не получилось т.к. ограничение в 30тысяч символов

```
    <div class="about-text">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 aria-label= "Me, Myself & I" class = "blast-root">
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden ="true" style= "opacity: 1;">M</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
                <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">,</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">M</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">y</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">s</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">l</span>
                <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">f</span>
                <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">&</span>
                <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">I</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="about-main-text">Im a Junior Java Back-End Developer located in Russia, Moscow.</p>
            <p class="about-main-text">Well-organised person with a great desire to develop in the IT sphere,responsible employee with high attention to job. Fan of MMA, Anime, Japan, Southern Korea</p>
            <p class="about-main-text">Interested in the entire back-end spectrum and looking for an internship with further employment</p>
            <p class = "txt about-main-text"><a href="contact.html" class = "special">Let`s make something special.</a></p>
            <div class="canvasSpehere"> 
                <div id="myCanvasContainer">
                    <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas" >
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML" target="_blank">HTML</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">Java</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer" target="_blank">REST</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON" target="_blank">JSON</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="13" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML" target="_blank">Stream Api</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS" target="_blank">Spring Boot</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress" target="_blank">Wordpress</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopify" target="_blank">Shopify</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="21" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js" target="_blank">Node JS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="17" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git" target="_blank">Git</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="17" href="" target="_blank">_lodash</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="23" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)" target="_blank">Bootstrap</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="15" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)" target="_blank">SASS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://reactjs.org/" target="_blank">ReactJS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="12" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery" target="_blank">jQuery</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://mongoosejs.com/" target="_blank">SQl</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://gulpjs.com/" target="_blank">Gulp</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://www.npmjs.com/" target="_blank">npm</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEM" target="_blank">BEM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about-text .container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.about-text h2 {
  color: rgb(32, 253, 220);
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.about-main-text {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(181, 174, 164);
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) .text-zone h2,
h2 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 4.2rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) .text-zone h2 {
  line-height: 4.9rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) h2 {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
}

.special {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 253, 220);
}

.txt {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1)
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1)
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
}

.rubberBand {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

.blast {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  letter-spacing: -17px;
}

.fake-blast {
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}

.canvasSphere {
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#myCanvasContainer {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#myCanvas {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#myCanvasContainer li a {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: font-file-82132;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/g2.png" alt="g2" class="navbar-pic"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link pt-4 navbar-link " href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pt-4 navbar-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pt-4 me-5 navbar-link" href="lofi-music.html">Lofi Music</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="https://github.com/Zesshhi" target="_blank" class="nav-link head-icons"><i class="bi bi-github"></i></a>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kirill-nefedov-284799246/" class="nav-link head-icons" target="_blank"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about-text">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 aria-label="Me, Myself & I" class="blast-root">
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">M</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
      <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">,</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">M</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">y</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">s</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">l</span>
      <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">f</span>
      <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">&</span>
      <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">I</span>
    </h2>
    <p class="about-main-text">Im a Junior Java Back-End Developer located in Russia, Moscow.</p>
    <p class="about-main-text">Well-organised person with a great desire to develop in the IT sphere,responsible employee with high attention to job. Fan of MMA, Anime, Japan, Southern Korea</p>
    <p class="about-main-text">Interested in the entire back-end spectrum and looking for an internship with further employment</p>
    <p class="txt about-main-text"><a href="contact.html" class="special">Let`s make something special.</a></p>
    <div class="canvasSpehere">
      <div id="myCanvasContainer">
        <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML" target="_blank">HTML</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">Java</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer" target="_blank">REST</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON" target="_blank">JSON</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="13" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML" target="_blank">Stream Api</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS" target="_blank">Spring Boot</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress" target="_blank">Wordpress</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopify" target="_blank">Shopify</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="21" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js" target="_blank">Node JS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="17" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git" target="_blank">Git</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="17" href="" target="_blank">_lodash</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="23" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)" target="_blank">Bootstrap</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="15" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)" target="_blank">SASS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://reactjs.org/" target="_blank">ReactJS</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="12" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery" target="_blank">jQuery</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://mongoosejs.com/" target="_blank">SQl</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://gulpjs.com/" target="_blank">Gulp</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://www.npmjs.com/" target="_blank">npm</a></li>
                            <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEM" target="_blank">BEM</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myCanvas.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/website-icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Istok+Web:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aboutStyle.css">
```

Как это исправить так,чтобы получилось как на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы зачем ссылку вставили как код? Потому что вас редактор предупредил, что ссылка должна сопровождаться кодом?

Comment: Да именно так,но я уже исправил и теперь ссылка нормально работает

Comment: Проблема далеко не в том как ссылка отображается, а в том что вы упорно игнорируете правила сообщества. Вы что думаете красоты ради это предупреждение показывалось? Вставьте сюда ваш минимальный воспроизводимый пример как код! А не ищите как бы обойти правила сообщества!

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения* **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Исправил так,как вы и сказали,теперь всё хорошо?

Comment: Уже намного лучше. Теперь откройте редактор вопроса, нажмите CTRL+M и вставьте вашу вёрстку и стили в нужные блоки, чтобы мы могли запустить ваш код. JS насколько я понимаю к вопросу не имеет отношения, потому его можно не вставлять, но если он нужен то вставьте. И главное не забудьте нажать на "Привести в порядок" перед тем вставить в сообщение, а так же запустите свой код и убедитесь что всё отображается как надо

Comment: Всё получилось @ez

Comment: А с какого перепуга они должны стоять рядом? Вообще ни вижу в коде ничего для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоке `about-text` есть блок с классом `container`. Ему нужно задать `display: flex;`. Далее разделить на два блока: часть с контентом поместив в отдельный див (будет слева), канвас с тегами (будет слева). Еще `#myCanvas` убрать `margin-left: 500px;`

Ниже пример:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about-text h2 {
  color: rgb(32, 253, 220);
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.about-main-text {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(181, 174, 164);
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) .text-zone h2,
h2 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 4.2rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) .text-zone h2 {
  line-height: 4.9rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) h2 {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
}

.special {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 253, 220);
}

.txt {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1)
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1)
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
}

.rubberBand {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

.blast {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  letter-spacing: -17px;
}

.fake-blast {
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}

.canvasSphere {
  width: 60%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#myCanvasContainer {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#myCanvas {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#myCanvasContainer li a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: font-file-82132;
}

.canvasSpehere {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Istok+Web:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="about-text">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div class="wrapp__left">
      <h2 aria-label="Me, Myself & I" class="blast-root">
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">M</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
        <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">,</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">M</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">y</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">s</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">e</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">l</span>
        <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">f</span>
        <span class="blast fake-blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">&</span>
        <span class="blast" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">I</span>
      </h2>
      <p class="about-main-text">Im a Junior Java Back-End Developer located in Russia, Moscow.</p>
      <p class="about-main-text">Well-organised person with a great desire to develop in the IT sphere,responsible employee with high attention to job. Fan of MMA, Anime, Japan, Southern Korea</p>
      <p class="about-main-text">Interested in the entire back-end spectrum and looking for an internship with further employment</p>
      <p class="txt about-main-text"><a href="contact.html" class="special">Let`s make something special.</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="canvasSpehere">
      <div id="myCanvasContainer">
        <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas">
            <ul>
              <li> <a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML" target="_blank">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">CSS</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="25" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">Java</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer" target="_blank">REST</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON" target="_blank">JSON</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="13" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML" target="_blank">Stream Api</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="14" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS" target="_blank">Spring Boot</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress" target="_blank">Wordpress</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="26" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopify" target="_blank">Shopify</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="21" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js" target="_blank">Node JS</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="17" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git" target="_blank">Git</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="17" href="" target="_blank">_lodash</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="23" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)" target="_blank">Bootstrap</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="15" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)" target="_blank">SASS</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="24" href="https://reactjs.org/" target="_blank">ReactJS</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="12" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery" target="_blank">jQuery</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://mongoosejs.com/" target="_blank">SQl</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="19" href="http://gulpjs.com/" target="_blank">Gulp</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://www.npmjs.com/" target="_blank">npm</a></li>
              <li><a data-weight="19" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEM" target="_blank">BEM</a></li>
            </ul>
          </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```